# Electromagnetic coupling on printed circuit board traces

Tags: pcb, antenna, electromagnetism, emc

When I applied the following damped signal in the proximity of my product (the magnitude is around 10 kV and the frequency is around 400 kHz) through a cable of 4 meters, the microcontroller sees a signal normally at 3V3 (HIGH LEVEL) which goes down to a LOW level (this appears very few times, I would say 1/100.)

[image: waveform]

I think this is a problem of electromagnetic coupling, even if at this frequency I should have a trace length equal to:

$$trace_{length} = \frac{c}{4*f}$$

Where \$c\$ is the speed of light and \$f\$ is the frequency of the signal.

So the trace length should be equal to 183 meters, which is clearly not the case.  The trace length is equal to around 10 cm. Nevertheless, when I plug a probe on the affected signal, i.e. I add a wire of 1 meter, it clearly works more often!

I would like to know: How can I confirm that it is a electromagnetic coupling and how can I protect my circuit from it? (Other than reducing the length of the trace.)

I think the problem is present on other signals, but the microcontroller is particularly sensitive to the fluctuation of this signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I would like to know: How can I confirm that it is a electromagnetic
> coupling and how can I protect my circuit from it?*

At 400 kHz and with the short length (10 cm) of "antenna" you used, the coupling is not electromagnetic but just plain ordinary electric coupling (one half of EM coupling). Basically, it's capacitive coupling of the 10 kV damped waveform to the input.

Protection methods: -

- rail clamping diodes
- series resistors
- parallel capacitors
- parallel TVS diodes
- a buffer circuit

Are the obvious ones to to try but, they might also "ruin" the signal that is on that line so you need to be a little more open about what that line is used for and what signals are on that line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! You mean there is a capacitor between the "antenna" and the source of the perturbation ? Why do you say that it is not an electromagnetic coupling ? This  is just a signal for detecting an event. It goes to "0V" when the event is detected. It is set to 0V via an optocoupler...

Comment: @Jess there's capacitance everywhere; parasitic capacitance. Proper EM coupling requires the antenna to be the necessary length and 10 cm is nowhere near so, it acts like one plate of a capacitor and the 10 kV is the other plate. In between is the dielectric (free space).

Comment: Thanks for this point ;)